# Getting error on npm install `npm WARN tar zlib: incorrect data check`

Tags: node.js, npm, aws-cloudformation, npm-install, aws-sam-cli

**What is happening?**
When I run `npm install` from my project directory, I am presented with this message:

```
npm WARN tar zlib: incorrect data check
npm WARN tarball cached data for acorn@https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn/-/acorn-7.4.1.tgz (sha512-nQyp0o1/mNdbTO1PO6kHkwSrmgZ0MT/jCCpNiwbUjGoRN4dlBhqJtoQuCnEOKzgTVwg0ZWiCoQy6SxMebQVh8A==) seems to be corrupted. Refreshing cache.
npm WARN tar zlib: incorrect data check
npm WARN tarball cached data for regexpp@https://registry.npmjs.org/regexpp/-/regexpp-2.0.1.tgz (sha512-lv0M6+TkDVniA3aD1Eg0DVpfU/booSu7Eev3TDO/mZKHBfVjgCGTV4t4buppESEYDtkArYFOxTJWv6S5C+iaNw==) seems to be corrupted. Refreshing cache.
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for regexpp@https://registry.npmjs.org/regexpp/-/regexpp-2.0.1.tgz (sha512-lv0M6+TkDVniA3aD1Eg0DVpfU/booSu7Eev3TDO/mZKHBfVjgCGTV4t4buppESEYDtkArYFOxTJWv6S5C+iaNw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for acorn@https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn/-/acorn-7.4.1.tgz (sha512-nQyp0o1/mNdbTO1PO6kHkwSrmgZ0MT/jCCpNiwbUjGoRN4dlBhqJtoQuCnEOKzgTVwg0ZWiCoQy6SxMebQVh8A==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure
npm WARN tar zlib: incorrect data check
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/compiler@https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/compiler/-/compiler-8.2.14.tgz (sha512-ABZO4E7eeFA1QyJ2trDezxeQM5ZFa1dXw1Mpl/+1vuXDKNjJgNyWYwKp/NwRkLmrsuV0yv4UDCDe4kJOGbPKnw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/compiler@https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/compiler/-/compiler-8.2.14.tgz (sha512-ABZO4E7eeFA1QyJ2trDezxeQM5ZFa1dXw1Mpl/+1vuXDKNjJgNyWYwKp/NwRkLmrsuV0yv4UDCDe4kJOGbPKnw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall stat
npm ERR! path /Users/USERNAME/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/00/16/4ee04ede785035432276b6b0decf17903396456b5757c3532997ffb5bee5c328d8c980dc966302a9fcdc1190b9abb2e574cafe140c20dee2424e19b3ca9f
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/USERNAME/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/00/16/4ee04ede785035432276b6b0decf17903396456b5757c3532997ffb5bee5c328d8c980dc966302a9fcdc1190b9abb2e574cafe140c20dee2424e19b3ca9f'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/USERNAME/.npm/_logs/2023-01-31T17_52_09_696Z-debug-0.log
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-api",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "docker-compose up -d; aws-vault exec nonprod -- sam local start-api -t sam-update.yml --docker-network sam-local --env-vars env.json",
    "build": "bash -c './bin/build.sh'",
    "deploy": "bash -c './bin/deploy.sh $npm_package_name $0 $1'",
    "invoke": "sam local invoke -t sam-update.yml --docker-network sam-local --env-vars env.json",
    "lint": "prettier-standard --format --lint './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,scss}'",
    "lint-ci": "prettier-standard --lint './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,scss}'",
    "meta": "bash -c './bin/meta.sh $npm_package_name $0 $1'",
    "package": "bash -c './bin/package.sh $npm_package_name $0 $1'",
    "postinstall": "pip install -r requirements-dev.txt && husky install",
    "setup": "bash -c './bin/setup.sh $npm_package_name $0 $1'",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest -u",
    "test:coverage": "mkdir -p ./src/coverage ; NODE_ENV=test jest --coverage | tee ./src/coverage/coverage.txt",
    "test-ci": "NODE_ENV=test jest --silent",
    "update": "bash -c './bin/update.sh $npm_package_name $0 $1'"
  },
  "license": "CC BY-SA",
  "keywords": [],
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^5.2.0",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "prettier-standard": "^16.4.1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "find-parent-dir": "0.3.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "env": {
      "jest": true,
      "node": true,
      "es6": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "sourceType": "module",
      "ecmaVersion": 2020
    },
    "ignorePatterns": [
      "**/node_modules/**",
      "**/*.spec.js"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json-summary",
      "text"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "<rootDir>/**/*.js"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/../.jest/setEnvVars.js"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>/layers/AuthorizerLayer/nodejs/node_modules",
      "<rootDir>/layers/PlagiarismLayer/nodejs/node_modules",
      "<rootDir>/layers/WebsocketLayer/nodejs/node_modules"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "/opt/(\\w*)": "<rootDir>/../src/layers/$1/$1.js",
      "aws-sdk": "<rootDir>/../__mocks__/aws-sdk",
      "aws-xray-sdk": "<rootDir>/../__mocks__/aws-xray-sdk"
    },
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "semi": true,
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "arrowParens": "avoid",
    "singleQuote": true
  }
}
```

**What I have tried to fix:**
The first thing I did was set a temporary cache location with `npm install --cache=/tmp/cache/` which didn't solve the issue. After that I just started throwing solutions hoping something would work without understanding fully what was happening. Should also note, first thing I did was delete all node_modules, and package-lock.json files within the repo.

- I ran `npm cache clean`
- Deleted the repo from my local machine and recloned
- Uninstalled node version (via nvm) and reinstalled
- Completely uninstalled node and nvm, deleted the `.node`, `.npm` and all other `*node*` folders on my mac, then restarted and reinstalled nvm and node

After all of that still getting the same error messages. If create a new directory on my machine and init a package.json and then run `npm install --save-dev husky prettier-standard jest` it all installs just fine. Leaving me to believe it is an issue with the repo, however, no one else on my team is experiencing this issue with the same repo on their machine. So not sure what is going on or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just had to delete the `node_modules` dir and the `package-lock.json`.